# Unable to perform rancher up command

Tags: ssh, rancher

we are trying to setup rancher. we are trying to start the rancher with a configuration file.but we are getting below error:

Can't retrieve Docker Info: error during connect: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info\": Unable to access node with address [35.196.155.104:22] using SSH. Please check if you are able to SSH to the node using the specified SSH Private Key and if you have configured the correct SSH username. Error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods